# EntityFramework Core database scaffolding (.NET Core RC2)

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-1.0, .net-core-rc2

I try to create an EntityFramework Core's model with an existing database (doc here : https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/platforms/aspnetcore/existing-db.html) but I have an error.

When I try the **Package Manager** method, I have the error :

```
The term "MY_DATABASE_NAME" is not recognize as a valid command applet [...]
```

This is the command I execute :

```
Scaffold-DbContext "'MY_CONNECTION_STRING'" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -outputDir MY_PATH -verbose
```

And when I try the **Command Prompt** method, I have this error :

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DispatchCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Create>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Here the command I execute :

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "'MY_CONNECTION_STRING'" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -outputDir MY_PATH -verbose
```

Before this question, I checked :

1. If I have installed good packages (*Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer*, *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools* and *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design*)
2. If my *project.json* was correct (tools, ...)
3. If my database was online, with good credentials

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to question titles. Indicate that the problem is solved by accepting an answer.

Comment: The original error could have been resolved by installing Powershell 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Succeed with **command prompt** :

1. Replaced *OutPutDir* by *o*
2. Removed verbose
3. Removed single quotes

Command :

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "MY_CONNECTION_STRING" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o MY_ABSOLUTE_PATH
```